# Where am I improperly allocating memory?

Tags: c++

I am only dynamically allocated memory for three class instances at a time, at the beginning of my while looop then I am deleting them at the end. Yet I keep getting a malloc error. At some points I was even getting a seg fault. I'm not exactly sure what I am doing wrong with my memory.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Song {
  public:
    string title;
    int time;
    int track;
};

class Album {
  public:
    map <int, Song *> songs;
    string name;
    int time;
};

class Artist {
  public:
    map <string, Album *> albums;
    string name;
    int time;
    int nsongs;
};

int stringToInt(string s) {
    int i = 0;

    i += ((s.c_str())[0] - '0') * 60;
    i += ((s.c_str())[2] - '0') * 10;
    i += ((s.c_str())[3] - '0');

    return i;
}

string intToString(int i) {
    string s;
    int m, s1, s2;
    char mc, s1c, s2c;

    m = i / 60;
    i -= m * 60;
    s1 = i / 10;
    i -= s1 * 10;
    s2 = i;

    mc = m + '0';
    s1c = s1 + '0';
    s2c = s2 + '0';
    s.push_back(mc);
    s.push_back(':');
    s.push_back(s1c);
    s.push_back(s2c);

    return s;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    string filename = argv[1];
    ifstream fin;
    string title, time, artist, album, genre;
    int track;
                   
    map <string, Artist *> artists;


    fin.open(filename);
    while (fin >> title >> time >> artist >> album >> genre >> track) {
        Artist* curArtist = new Artist();
        Song* curSong = new Song();
        Album* curAlbum = new Album();

        replace(title.begin(), title.end(), '_', ' ');
        replace(artist.begin(), artist.end(), '_', ' ');
        replace(album.begin(), album.end(), '_', ' ');


        if (artists.find(artist) != artists.end()) {
            cout << "Old Artist: " << artist << endl;
            if (artists[artist]->albums.find(album) != artists[artist]->albums.end()) {
                cout << "Old Album: " << album << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << "New Album: " << album << endl;
                artists[artist]->albums.insert({album, curAlbum});
            }
        }
        else {
            cout << "New Artist: " << artist << endl;
            artists.insert({artist, curArtist});
            cout << "New Album: " << album << endl;
            artists[artist]->albums.insert({album, curAlbum});
        }

        curSong->title = title;
        curSong->track = track;
        curSong->time = stringToInt(time);
        artists[artist]->name = artist;

        delete curArtist;
        delete curSong;
        delete curAlbum;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It also might be worth noting that I don't get a malloc or seg fault right away. If I am reading in a smaller file, I don't get any error codes. It's only after I read in a few hundred lines.

Comment: `artists[artist]->albums.find(album) != curArtist->albums.end()` compare unrelated iterators...

Comment: You are storing references to instances of classes inside maps and then freeing the classes. That's a problem!

Comment: Using smart pointer might make ownership more explicit.

Comment: @Jarod42 thank you, I have fixed that, but I am still getting a seg fault.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Okay, I see what you are saying, but how should I go about creating an instance for every artist, song, and album if I don't allocate that memory in a loop?

Comment: @IanBurns you are correct to allocate it. You are incorrect to de-allocate it. You should only de-allocate it when you don't need it (e.g. old artist or old album).

Answer (score 1):

Well, the shown code does this:

```
artists[artist]->albums.insert({album, curAlbum});
```

right before it does this:

```
delete curAlbum;
```

The `artists` map, therefore, ends up holding pointers to destroyed objects, when all is said and done. A pointer to `curAlbum` gets inserted into the map, then `curAlbum` gets `delete`d. Then, subsequently, these objects are referenced elsewhere, this is undefined behavior. Strike one.

```
artists[artist]->albums.find(album) != curArtist->albums.end()
```

This ends up comparing iterators from two unrelated containers. This is also undefined behavior. Strike two.

Strike three is called "Pointless Use Of Pointers". Nothing in the shown code requires pointers, `new`, and `delete`. Just by getting rid of all the pointers, replacing `map <string, Artist *>` with `map <string, Artist>`, `map<string, Album *>` with `map<string, Album>`, and `map <int, Song *>` with `map<int, Song>` eliminates the need to `new` or `delete` anything, and eliminates one of the most common source of bugs in C++ code: Pointless Use Of Pointers. It is logically impossible to misuse pointers and dynamic memory allocation when they are not ever used.

After all, this is why containers like `map`, `vector`, and others exist in the C++ library: they automatically `new` and `delete` its contents for you, do it correctly, so that you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Thank you, I was given a skeleton of the classes from my professor, and I didn't understand why we needed to use pointers, but I assumed there was just something I am missing. It doesn't seem like I need to though.

Comment: Sadly, you would not be the first poster on Stackoverflow to bring evidence of an incompetent C++ instructor. If your C++ instructor wants you to use pointers, for this, then you should find a different C++ instructor.

Comment: Touch crowd today, good answer, solves the issue, not selected as the answer or upvoted. I can help with one.